# Why $\hom(f,g)$ consists of all pairs $(\alpha,\beta)$, where $\alpha:A\rightarrow{B}$ and $\beta:B\rightarrow{D}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I am a beginner in abstract algebra and I am reading Hungerford's abstract algebra book. In his book, after he gives the definitions of categories, I'm quite confused by the example he has given:

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be any category and define the category $\mathcal{D}$ whose objects are all morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$. If $f:A\rightarrow{B}$ and $g:C\rightarrow{D}$ are morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$, then $\hom(f,g)$ consists of all pairs $(\alpha,\beta)$, where $\alpha:A\rightarrow{C}$ and $\beta:B\rightarrow{D}$ are morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$.

What confused me is that what is the element of $\hom(f,g)$ and why the element must be pairs.Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I think there is a typo, you should have $\alpha: A \to \mathbf{C}$. Also, the morphisms consist of all pairs $(\alpha, \beta)$ such that $\beta \circ f = g \circ \alpha$ (or probably, such that some diagram that is drawn commutes)

Comment: We are defining a new category, so there is no "why must". You can do anything you like, as long as the definition of category is satisfied.

Comment: Sry, there is a typo. I have edited it now.Thanks for your comment. I get what he means now. I was quite confused about finding a concrete mapping to desctibe the the element of $\hom(f,g)$, but there is no need if we can draw the diagram and easily satisfys the conditions that show it's a category.

Comment: I’m not sure you understand from that last comment. The diagram drawing referred to by Noam has nothing to do with checking $D$ meets the axioms of a category. We could define $\hom(f,g)$ in many different ways so that $D$ is a category. This is just the canonical CHOICE that makes it a convenient category to think about